# How to give space between two dcc components in Python Dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

What is the HTML equivalent for &nbsp (space) in Dash?

```
html.Div(
    [
      dcc.Input(),
      <add horizontal space here> 
      dcc.Input()
    ]
)
```

Comment: Have you checked these [1](https://community.plotly.com/t/spacing-for-core-components-html/12552/3) and [2](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-leave-some-space-on-the-page-between-graphs-and-drop-down-menus/6234) out?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to add some space between components you can simply use CSS-properties for this:

```
html.Div(
    [
      dcc.Input(),
      dcc.Input(style={"margin-left": "15px"})
    ]
)
```

This adds a margin to the left of your second Input.

Have a look at the layout-section in the Plotly Dash documentation and CSS documentation about margin:

- https://dash.plotly.com/layout
- https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_margin-left.asp

Comment: Worked! I always thought I had to use `padding-X`, and not `margin-X`, but I was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use **html.Br()** as shown below:

```
html.Div(
    [
      dcc.Input(),
      html.Br(),
      dcc.Input()
    ]
)
```

for more info,
pls checkout below links:

- https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/br
- https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/124931/dash_html_components.Br

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).